# Put an image inside a webview and fit it width

Tags: java, android, webview

I'd like to use a WebView for displaying images potentially big (in order to seize it memory management).
For the test i'm loading this code in the WebView

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <img alt="test" src="file:///android_asset/cute-cat-sleeping.jpg">
</body>
```

The problem is that if I load it in a web "as is". The WebView only allow to zoom out until the first dimension of the image is fit in screen. In this example the image height is totally shown into the WebView and then no more zoom allowed:

[image: No zoom no setUseWideViewPort]

As you can see this mode doesn't allow a correct display of the global image despite that when the image is zoomed the behaviour in the right and bottom corners are correct as you can see here

[image: correct zoom display]

So I tried the **(WebView).getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true)** and the result is that I can zoom out more than the image's width

[image: with setUseWideViewPort]

and the zoomed behaviour is not correct in the bottom-right borders:

[image: zoom with setUseWideViewPort]

Summarizing: I'd like the max zoom out possible to be imageWidth=webview width and zoom behaviour like in the second image:

[image]

Complete and/or usefull answers will be bountied

EDIT: Bounty opened for Vinayak.B

Comment: Not sure. But try to edit the html. set the width of <img> to 100%.

Comment: it makes strange behaviour with the zoom like jumps to diferent zones than the zoomed ones =(

Comment: Does it fit in the window? like the last image? Maybe you can control the zooming or other behavour using javascript & css.

Comment: Yep it fits but for example when I try to zoom in the bottom right corner the scroll jumps instantly to the top left. I'll try with JS & CSS

Comment: Ok. Try to set the width in `onLoad()` of body using `javascript` instead of inside `img` tag. Whatever.. try and let us know the result. ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Using Viewport Metadata](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#Metadata) may help you to do this

The viewport is the area in which your web page is drawn. Although the viewport's visible area matches the size of the screen, the viewport has its own dimensions that determine the number of pixels available to a web page

Also try below

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Answer (score 6):

Load Html file in Webview and put your image in asset folder and read that image file using Html.

```
<htm>
  <table>
   <tr>
         <td>
           <img src="cat.gif" width="100%" alt="Hello">
         </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Now Load that Html file in Webview

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc.html");
```

Or another way

if you use LinearLayout, can take a background parameter that can be a colour or a resource.

So in main.xml file contains webview. you simply added a

```
android:background="@+drawable/backgroundmain"
```

and use

```
   web.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

To make the webview transparent to see the background image behind.

Answer (score 4):

here is the solution set the img tag width to 100% in HTML code and then load it in your webview using `loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htnlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` method

try this code

```
String htnlString = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body style = \"text-align:center\"><img src=\"http://shiaislamicbooks.com/books_snaps/UR335/1.jpg\" alt=\"pageNo\" width=\"100%\"></body></html>";
yourWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htnlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your Webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```